# efk_elasticsearch_1 exited with code 78 when install ElasticSearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

When I am installing ElasticSearch using docker-compose(CentOS 7.6\MAC OS),runing command '`docker-compose up`' ,it throw this error '`efk_elasticsearch_1 exited with code 78`',this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.2.0
    expose:
      - 9200
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you need to run this in your `HOST` terminal not the container:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

if you check the container logs you will see something like this:

```
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

please note also the above command will be reseted after rebooting your machine, you need to set the value in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it permenant.

see [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html)

Comment: Is it possible not reboot machine?@LinPy /sbin/sysctl -p not work for me

Comment: yes just run : `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` and re-run your container

Comment: If running in kubernetes, what would be equivalent to _"HOST terminal"_? It should be the node where the pod is placed, or in all nodes?

Comment: Thank you! A lot of people give this advice, but only you mentioned that it should be executed on host machine

Answer (score 5):

**Using the Docker images in production** or local

The following requirements and recommendations apply when running Elasticsearch in Docker in production.

Set vm.max_map_count to at least 262144
The vm.max_map_count kernel setting must be set to at least 262144 for production use.

How you set vm.max_map_count depends on your platform.

**Linux**

To view the current value for the vm.max_map_count setting, run:

```
grep vm.max_map_count /etc/sysctl.conf
vm.max_map_count=262144
```

To apply the setting on a live system, run:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

To permanently change the value for the vm.max_map_count setting, update the value in /etc/sysctl.conf.

**macOS with Docker for Mac**

The vm.max_map_count setting must be set within the xhyve virtual machine:

From the command line, run:

screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
Press enter and use sysctl to configure vm.max_map_count:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

To exit the screen session, type Ctrl a d.

**Windows and macOS with Docker**

The vm.max_map_count setting must be set via docker-machine:

```
docker-machine ssh
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

**Windows with Docker Desktop WSL 2 **

The vm.max_map_count setting must be set in the docker-desktop container:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Answer (score 4):

This made it for me:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

On powershell & WSL 1