Elasticsearch died while starting up, with exit code 78
Im trying to run Elasticsearch using the command
./bin/elasticsearch

as it says in the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html documentation, and after it starts running i keep getting this error. I runned it a few days ago and it worked just fine, few days after (today) cant run it anymore, after a while of not trying to solve it, i rollbacked the server and started every step from the beginning. In the screenshot you can see the log file
Has anyone occurred this Error?

May be not enough memory? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937171/efk-elasticsearch-1-exited-with-code-78-when-install-elasticsearch#56982026
